# A moment sequence and Motzkin numbers. Modular coincidence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I was looking at two sequences of integers, both with prominent place is combinatorics. The first one appears, for instance, in [Stieltjes moment sequences for pattern-avoiding permutations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00393.pdf) (see page 23)
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{2k}k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n+2}{k+1}}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}.$$
The second appears in lattice path enumerations as [Motzkin numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number) (a close cousin of Catalan numbers)
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}\frac{\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}k}{k+1}.$$

In modulo $2$ arithmetic, I run into what seems to be a (happy) coincidence. Let me ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$a_n\equiv b_n \mod 2.$$

**ADDED.** $a_n$ or $b_n$ is even iff $n$ is part of [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A081706) listed on OEIS. In fact, whenever that happens, $\nu_2(a_n)=1$ and $\nu_2(b_n)\in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A005802 and https://oeis.org/A001006, from what I checked here they agree mod 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with $b_n$. Since Catalan number $C_k$ is odd iff $k=2^m-1$, from [Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) it follows that
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{2k}C_k \equiv\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{n}{2(2^m-1)}\equiv 1+\nu_2(\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1)\pmod2,$$
where $\nu_2(\cdot)$ is the 2-adic valuation.

---

Now consider $a_n$. From the recurrence given in [OEIS A005802](http://oeis.org/A005802),
$$(n^2 + 8n + 16)a_{n+2}=(10n^2 + 42n + 41)a_{n+1}-(9n^2 + 18n + 9)a_n,$$
we have $a_{2k+1}\equiv a_{2k}\pmod2$ for all $k$. It's therefore sufficient to consider even $n$, when
$$a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{k=0}^n C_k \binom{n+1}{k+1} \binom{n+1}{k} \equiv \sum_{m\geq 0} \binom{n+1}{2^m} \binom{n+1}{2^m-1}\equiv \nu_2(n+2)\pmod2.$$

---

Hence, for all $n$ we have
$$a_n\equiv b_n\pmod{2}.$$

Comment: Max: can you say a few words on the reason for congruence with the $2$-adic valuations?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: By Lucas theorem $\binom{n}{2(2^m-1)}\equiv \binom{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{2^m-1}\pmod2$, and the latter binomial coefficient is odd iff $\lfloor n/2\rfloor\equiv 2^m-1\pmod{2^m}$, i.e. $\nu_2(\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1)\geq m$.